# Reset tinyMce content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to reset tinymce content.

On the beginning there is some 'A content'. User changed it to some 'B content', but he don't want to save it, so he can click 'cancel' button and whole content is back to 'A' version.

A content is text saved earlier, so it's not constant. How to reset tinyMce text to original one?
Html:

```
<div id="someDiv">Content A</div>
```

Would be nice to see something like this. If content was modified, cancel button will reset content to original:

```
if($('#someDiv').tinymce().isDirty()) {:
    $('#someDiv').tinymce().reset();
}
```

Comment: Yes, bravo CBroe. You know that i've visited almost all the results from few first pages of this query before i posted here?
If you will find there answer for my question, then post, and don't treat me like an idiot!

Comment: I can’t know that you did any research of your self before if you don’t mention that in any way.

Comment: Well, sorry. I also don't like when ppl don't search before question, so I understand your intention.
All results I found are about clearing editor, but not about reset to its beginning state.
Also found few examples that doesn't work :(

So I'm still waiting for help.

Comment: I doubt that a simple “reset” is even possible – since these editors actually manipulate DOM content on the fly. I guess one would have to “save”/clone the original DOM node the editor is called upon before doing so – and then have the actual, user-manipulated DOM replaced by this copy of the original nodes when one wants to “reset” everything to its original state.

Comment: Yes. This is what i have done now. Because this is div and not form element the js reset will not help.

I had little hope that there is some built in function to reset tinyMCE content and I just can't find it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done.

You need to add this (using [the setup parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:setup)) to your configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
          ed.init_content = ed.getContent();
      });
   }
});
```

on buttonclick you call the following to reset the editor content

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
ed.setContent(ed.init_content);
```

**EDIT** - For tinymce 4.x the syntax for attaching editor events has changed and is now:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function () {
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Give me a second. Must figure out how to pin up this using jQuery plugin.

Comment: It works perfectly. This is almost the same what i did (save data somewhere on init) but this is much nicer. Don't have to create temporary elements or other stuff.

jQuery wersion is almost the same.
`$('yourElement').tinymce().setContent($('yourElement').tinymce().init_content)`

Comment: glad to have been able of help, onInit has to be used here because otherwise you wouldn't kniow for sure if the editor is ready

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert, where should I put `var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id'); ed.setContent(ed.init_content);` and how do I create the button?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is include this `<input type="reset" value="reset">` into tinymce

Comment: you may call this code from the main document - if you have loaded tinymce as intended the varaible tinymce will be available there

Comment: to insert the desired content into the editor you may call ed.setContent = "<input type="reset" value="reset">" and you will need to make sure that input elements are configured as valid_elements and valid_children

Comment: I copy/pasted your code but I'm getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined', what gives? Using TinyMCE 4.0.8

Comment: @Thariama: Yes I did, after a while I found this alternative solution which does work for me: ed.on('init',function(){this.OrigVal = this.getContent();}); This works fine on my 4.0.8 tinyMCE but your solution kept throwing the error